# translating the following ternary operator into regular if statements?

Tags: jquery

I am new to web programming and haven't dealt much with ternary operators. I found some sample code for a jquery slider but I need to edit it so that it stops when the user moves their mouse over the banner. I was hoping someone could help me turn the code below into a simple set of if and else if statements that I am more used to dealing with. Thanks in advance.

```
//Get next image, when it reaches the end, rotate it back to the first image 

var next = ((current.next().length) ? ((current.next().hasClass('show')) ? $('div.rotator ul li:first') :current.next()) : $('div.rotator ul li:first'));
```

Comment: Start from the innermost pair of parentheses and work your way outwards.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent without using the ternary operator is:

```
var next;
if (current.next().length) {
   if (current.next().hasClass('show')) {
      next = $('div.rotator ul li:first')
   }
   else {
      next = current.next();
   }
}
else {
   next = $('div.rotator ul li:first'));
}
```

Comment: you are awesome thank you! I see now what was confusing me was the nested if statements.

Answer (score 1):

You should know that ternary operator is in this format:

```
condition ? if true : else
```

Write it this way and try to translate it:

```
var next = ((current.next().length)
            ?
                ((current.next().hasClass('show'))
                ?
                    $('div.rotator ul li:first')
                :
                    current.next())
            :
                $('div.rotator ul li:first'));
```

Now that you can visualize it like an if/else block, its just a matter of changing the syntax.

```
var next;
if (current.next().length) {
    if (current.next().hasClass('show')) {
        next = $('div.rotator ul li:first');
    } else {
        next = current.next());
    }
} else {
    next = $('div.rotator ul li:first');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the equivalent in `if` / `else`:

```
var next;
if (current.next.length) {
    if (current.next().hasClass('show')) {
         next = $('div.rotator ul li:first');
     } else {
        next = current.next();
    }
} else {
    next = $('div.rotator ul li:first');
}
```